# In C should return 0 print anything to the console?

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in Xcode I see at the bottom, "Program ended with exit code: 0," however when I type "./a.out" in the terminal to run the program, it prints "Hello World!" as expected, but nothing else.

I expected to some something in reference to 0 being returned. If return 0 is to let me know that the program exited correctly, shouldn't I see something in reference to the 0 being retuned, if it exited correctly? Unless return isn't supposed to print anything, then in that case how would I know what was returned? If I can't see it printed to the console.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode always returns the exit code of the program, for debugging purposes, return does not print for main().

Comment: So I guess to know if my program exited correctly, I have to use "echo $?" right?

Comment: @tony Most shells also provide features for this; in `tcsh` I do `set printexitvalue` to show the exit value if it's non-0, and I can also show the last exit status in my prompt (so you never need to do `echo $?`) ... I believe `bash` & `zsh` can also do this, but I don't know how since I rarely use these (...you'll have to look up that yourself, or ask a question about it)

Comment: @anoyd_bi_me_grammers it's not obvious, if he doesn't `return` any error code it will always return `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The termination status of the program is handled by the hosting environment in a platform-specific way, i.e. in any way it sees fit. Development environments will usually display the programs's termination status. Regular terminals by default do not.

So, stop expecting anything to be printed in response to the returned `0`. It is not supposed to be printed. You are not supposed to "know" what was returned, unless you take special deliberate steps to find out.

In most cases the termination status will be handled quietly, meaning that most of the time you will not print it. You will analyze it in execution environment and make further decisions based on the results of that analysis. But if you want the hosting execution environment to print it, you can ask it explicitly, by doing `echo $?` in *nix terminals or `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` in Windows ones.

Answer (score 1):

The return value from `main()` is the exit code of the program, it's not meant to be printed.

Xcode is reporting the exit code of the program.

If you want to print it on the console just do

```
./a.out
echo $?
```

If you want to notify the program invoker that something went wrong, then you can `return SOME_ERROR_CODE;` from `main()` it's equivalent to `exit(SOME_ERROR_CODE);`  but it's cleaner to `return` an error code from `main()`.

Xcode will just tell you about the `exit` code of your program and in case you need to know why the program exited then a meaningful `exit` code value would help.

In the console the `$?` is a special variable where the exit code of the last command is stored, in `sh` scripts you will find that often a check for `$?` is made right after executing a command.

Answer (score 1):

Return 0 does not print anything.   For debugging purposes, programs you write notify you when the program has completed it's execution